# Keep object in memory and avoid reloading pickle

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, memory-management, pickle

I am working with a decent amount finacial data that I store in a python collection of objects. I am initially getting the data from text files, creating the objects and then pickeling them, so that I do bot have to go through the process of creating the objects again. The pickle size is close to 1 gb.

Loading the pickle takes about 1 min 30 seconds. I need to reduce the amount it takes the pickle to load.  I am running diferent simulations stopping and starting the runs. Therefore everytime I re run the simulation, I need to reload the pickle.

I tried to solve the issue by creating a singleton and hopefully load the pickle just once. Afterwards I hoped that I could access the singleton in other “runs” and not have the need to reload it as it was already in memory. However, that is not working. I am lookimg for a solution to keep the object in memory without the need to reload the pickle.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but have you considered using a proper database to store your data in, rather than keeping it all in pickle files?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have tried [Pyro](https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/)?
According to what I understood, you need something like a in-memory computing pipeline. This is very used for in-memory data processing (dataflow) on distributed systems. It works like a client-server architecture. You can create a script (server-side) that loads your pickle object in memory (only one time) and wait for remote calls from the client-side (even if they are on the same machine). You can find some examples here:

- Hosting Pyro objects: https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/servercode.html
- Calling remote objects: https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/clientcode.html

Hope this will help you.

Comment: that documentation is out of date. The latest one is here https://pyro4.readthedocs.io/